# Calling stored procedure from pgsql-http doesn't store values in my trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am using the pgsql-http extension inside PostgreSQL to get some values from another api whenever I insert values into a table called "evaluations". The JSON from the api is returned correctly but I can't store the necessary fields from the JSON in my table.
I am quite new to PL/pgsql and can't get my head around it.

Here is my function with the API call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION falko_organizer.get_json_amadeus_codes(
    code TEXT, email TEXT, first_name  TEXT, last_name TEXT)
    RETURNS json AS
$$
DECLARE
    result json;
    url varchar := 'https://myApiUrl/api/create-evaluation/' || code;
    body varchar := '{"email": "' || email || '", "teacher_name": "' || first_name || ' ' || last_name || '"}';
BEGIN
    SELECT content::json INTO result
    FROM http_post(url, body, 'application/json');

    RETURN result;
end
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And here is the trigger function together with the trigger I call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION falko_organizer.trigger_get_json_amadeus_codes()
    RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$$
    DECLARE result json;
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMP TABLE teacher (
        email TEXT, first_name TEXT, last_name TEXT
    );
    INSERT INTO teacher (email, first_name, last_name)
    SELECT t.email, t.first_name, t.last_name
    FROM falko_organizer.teachers t
    WHERE t.teacher_id = NEW.teacher_id;

    SELECT falko_organizer.get_json_amadeus_codes(
        NEW.code,
       (SELECT email from teacher),
       (SELECT first_name from teacher),
       (SELECT last_name from teacher)) INTO result;

    NEW.amadeus_evaluation_code := result->>'evaluation_id';
    NEW.amadeus_status_code := result->>'status_code';

    DROP TABLE teacher;
    RETURN NEW;
end
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER insert_amadeus_codes
    AFTER INSERT ON falko_organizer.evaluations
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION falko_organizer.trigger_get_json_amadeus_codes();
```

When I just call get_json_amadeus_codes with dummy values, it correctly returns the following JSON string:

```
SELECT falko_organizer.get_json_amadeus_codes(
    'REL123412341234', 'test@mail.com', 'Tester', 'Testy');

---------
returns: {"evaluation_id": "931bc65a-3217-49bc-902f-7cd3cfd86763", "status_code": "cd246604-e7d2-468c-baf9-f2e275d47905"}
```

When I insert a new evaluation, the trigger is called and I can see at my api that the codes have been created and sent via json, but the fields "amadeus_evaluation_code" and "amadeus_status_code" keep empty in my evaluations table after the insert.

Comment: Modifying data `after insert` is expected to have no effect... try with a `before insert` trigger.

Comment: PS: try your code with a name like `test"fail`

Comment: As @JGH mentioned this `RETURN NEW;` won't return anything in an `AFTER TRIGGER` per [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): *The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @JGH and @adrian-klaver mentioned in their comments: I just had to change `AFTER INSERT` to `BEFORE INSERT`.